# Can't use PropertyChanged from ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm puzzled. I try using the `PropertyChanged` event from an `ObservableCollection`, but the compiler does not know the event. `CollectionChanged` he knows. MSDN says the `ObservableCollection` has the event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653376.aspx). What am I doing wrong?

```
ObservableCollection<int> xx = new ObservableCollection<int>();
xx.PropertyChanged += (s, a) => { };
```

Comment: ObservableCollection is meant for monitoring collections INotifyPropertyChanged is for properties.

Answer (score 5):

`PropertyChanged` is a `protected event`, that's why it's not accessible from your code. As you surely know, `protected` means it's accessible only from itself and from derived classes.

When it comes to `ObservableCollection`, we have an event `CollectionChanged` to know, when the collection changes (an item got deleted or added). If we need to know, if the item of the collection has been changed, you need to use a custom implementation, for example from here: [TrulyObservableCollection](https://gist.github.com/itajaja/7507120)

Also, as @O. R. Mapper correctly pointed out, there's is a way of doing this without creating a derived type. As `ObservableCollection` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` explicitly, you have to cast the instance to the interface and then you can access properties, events and methods of the interface. So something like this works as well (but it's ugly to be honest):

```
ObservableCollection<int> xx = new ObservableCollection<int>();
((INotifyPropertyChanged)xx).PropertyChanged += (s, a) => { };
```

Comment: I knew, but I didn't notice. Thanks.

Comment: "that's why it's not accessible from your code" - of course, it can still be accessed from the outside. As `ObservableCollection<T>` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, it must provide all members of `INotifyPropertyChanged` in a publicly accessible fashion, in this case as an [explicit interface implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460458.aspx). Hence, FWIW, `((INotifyPropertyChanged)xx).PropertyChanged += (s, a) => { };` should still do the trick. I haven't checked, but I could imagine that event is even fired, e.g. when the `Count` property changes.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, yes, even though it's true, it's ugly as hell and somewhat feel hacky about it... But you're right, it should be probably mentioned in the answer.